# Marketing Cloud Automation Studio Triggered Automation not sending to all emails on Data Extension

Tags: email, dataextensions, automationstudio, triggered-send

We have a Triggered Automation email setup through Automation Studio that's not sending to everyone in the Data Extension (DE).

The trigger is the new csv file dropped into the Enhanced ftp. The first step after the trigger Imports the data from that csv file into a DE. The second step sends the email to the subscribers in the DE. All of these steps work, but not all emails are being sent to the full DE list. In our tests only emails in the DE that are on our All_Subscribers list are sent the email, not the new subscribers.

Any ideas on why emails don't get sent to the new subscribers/emails in the DE? A ticket has been opened with Salesforce and we're waiting for their feedback too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the send relationship set up for the data extension? If you are using a subscriber key field to relate to 'all subscribers' you also need a field with Email Address data type in order to have previously-not-created-subscribers created.

Comment: In the Data Extension, under Type we do have 'Subscriber Key' relating to Subscribers on 'Subscriber Key'. We also have a field called 'Email Address' in our Data Extension that's being populated by the csv Import. One thing unique about our setup is that the 'Subscriber Key' is not the 'Email Address' it's our CRM system's customer ID since we allow our customers to share an email address, could it be related to that?

Comment: Question: is your Email Address field of Email Address data type or text?

Comment: It was 'text' I changed the data type for the Email Address column to 'Email Address' and it works now.